# Cannot sync games data in China though VPN is available

Tags: google-play-games

The game is already available on Google Play and gets ready for players to sync game process while the Internet is connected. Because of China is limited to the relevant services, so it should be syncing when the VPN is on theoretically. 
But this cannot work in reality. Many players are giving us feedback that they could not sync their data even they are using VPN services. Sometimes, they are losing the game process. 
I'm wondering the reasons why they could not be synced while they are connecting to the Internet. 
Maybe: The VPN is not stable or it should be turned on last for at least 24 hours? Are there any method or tool can check whether the Internet connection is stable to sync? 
I'm looking forward to a response. Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to cloud save or multiplayer services?

Comment: Cloud save for syncing data through multi devices.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a lot like the VPNs those people use aren't a good fit. It's true that it's hard to pass by China's VPN restrictions. Here are some points good VPN that works OK in China should have:
- fast speed and advanced encryption system
- kill switch
- by pass Great Firewall
- I think the most important is to have servers located in the neighborhood countries.
But I know that some players claim that they have a pretty solid VPN provider, but their guns won't shoot on time or the player stand still when it has to run.

China does its best to block VPNs, I guess this is the biggest problem.
Anyway, make sure you check the points above.